# Por que Include no me trae los usuarios con los que esta relacionado, solo los cuenta

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

Buen dia 
actualmente tengo tres tablas la materia(Subject), usuario y la relacion materia_usuario(Enroll_Teacher_Subject). estoy haciendo una consulta en el controlador en la cual quiero que me muestre la materia y las relaciones con la tabla materia_usuario. Cuando realizo la consulta trae bien la los datos de la tabla materia pero cuando trae la informacion de la tabla materia_usuario solo me trae la cantidad de relaciones que existe y quiero me muestra es detallamente la informacion. esta informacion la quiero mostrar en una pagina que recibe el modelo materia

esta es la tabla materia

```
public class Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]//only you can to write 50 characters
    [Display(Name = "Nombre de la Materia")]
    public string NameSubject { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Descripcion de la Materia")]
    public string DescriptionSubject { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Grado")]
    public int LevelId { get; set; }

    public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enroll_Teacher_Subject> Enroll_Teacher_Subjects { get; set; }
}
```

La tabla relacion usuario_materia

```
public class Enroll_Teacher_Subject
{
    [Key]
    public int Enroll_Teacher_SubjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Fecha Matricula ")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime DateEnroll_Teacher_Subject { get; set; }


    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Display(Name = "Observaciones")]
    public string ObservationEnroll_Teacher_Subject { get; set; }



    [Display(Name = "Profesor")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual UserSchool UserSchool { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Materia")]
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Anno lectivo")]
    public int AnnoLectivoId { get; set; }
    public virtual AnnoLectivo AnnoLectivo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Enroll_Student_Subject_Teacher> Enroll_Student_Subject_Teachers { get; set; }

}
```

Este es el controlador donde quiero hacer la pregunta

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }



        var SubjectList = await db.Subjects
                                        .Include(x => x.Enroll_Teacher_Subjects)                                            
                                        .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.SubjectId == 5);


        if (SubjectList == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(SubjectList);

    }
```

El error al que me refiero es este
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas seguro que para el  SubjectId = 5 hay registros de Enroll_Teacher_Subjects ? Recuerda que en EF 6 no necesitas mapear la tabla intermedia si quiere relacionar los Subjects con los Teacher

Comment: lo que no entendi es porque dices que trae la cantidad pero no el detalle ? como ese eso, no sera que lo estas viendo en debug y debes usar la opcion de "Results View"

Comment: Si existen registro con SubjectId = 5

Comment: exactamento lo que aparece es Enroll_Teacher_Subjects Count = 2

Comment: @LeandroTuttini exactamento lo que pretendo hacer es que una vez llegue el modelo subject a la view tambien contenga el objeto Enroll_Teacher_Subjects y mostrar toda la informacion por medio de un foreach(var item in model.Enroll_Teacher_Subjects)

Comment: o sea en debug visualizas un count = 2 para esa propiedad pero al realizar el foreach no itera ?

Comment: Correcto eso me pasa... soy nuevo programando y no se como solucionar

Comment: si en la imagen que muestras desplegas los items de la lista que visualizas ?

Comment: Nada solo count = 2

Comment: a la izquierda de la propiedad tienes una fecha con forma de triangulo, si la pulsas deberia desplegar esos dos items, el count=2 indica la cantidad de items que va a desplegar

Comment: Si me trae dos objetos con su respectiva informacion

Comment: entonces el linq esta correcto, sino lo renderiza quizas es un tema con la view